# Extract text from PDF file that's saved as image only on Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdftotext

I am trying to extract text from pdf file using python. So I am using pdftotext to convert pdf files to txt.

My code below works fine with files where I can left click and drag words or search(ctrl+f) by words.

```
import pdftotext
import os

directory = "/Downloads/test" # path where PDF files are saved

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pathname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        
        with open(pathname, 'rb') as f:
            pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f) # ERROR : poppler error creating document
            
        txtname = pathname.replace('.pdf', '.txt')
        with open(txtname, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as text_file: # edit: encoding utf-8 added
            for page in pdf:
                text_file.write(page)
        continue
```

However for some pdf files like the one in the link below, where I can open the file and read but can't drag any words, code does not properly work. It only extracts draggable text.

How can I fix this problem? Do I have to use any other parameter or is there any other package to solve this problem?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UtyGRmyKIV5O3Fx2-Ug_oTpv-7anXuKU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think there's no problem. You shouls use OCR for this problem.

Comment: *"code does not properly work"* - but it does work properly. As there is hardly any *text* in the document (*text* being drawn using PDF text showing instructions), *text extraction* will extract hardly any text. All the text which is in bitmap images only, needs to be extracted using OCR.

Comment: @mkl Thank you. I figured out what the problem was but couldn't find a Python package that has OCR function

Comment: @DaisukeAkagawa Thank you. Is there any python package that can run OCR?